# C# continuous reading from serial port

Tags: c#

I am trying to continuously read data that is being sent from arduino to serial port using C# and display it somewhere. What is the best approach to do ??

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question. Start with this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This depends greatly on your business rules (which we don't have) but in general, I've found that trying to read continuously is fraught with issues and leads  to unnecessary complexity. It's usually beter to handle the [DataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) event.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `SerialPort.ReadLine method`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport

```
    var serialPort = new SerialPort();

    // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
    serialPort.PortName = ..;
    serialPort.BaudRate = ..;
    serialPort.Parity = ..;
    serialPort.DataBits = ..;
    serialPort.StopBits = ..;
    serialPort.Handshake = ..;

    string message = serialPort.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I tried all of these my problem is that i am experimenting with arduino and i am trying to read the potentiometer on C# thus when it's changed the value on C# is changed.